# how to integrate firebase in webapp using android firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-authentication

android database is create and i want to authenticate it using html page.
it is not working code is given below.
here basically we have a html login page and script to authenticate it from fire-base database.provide with the solution code or what's wrong with my code or something missing in it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <!-- /////////////////firebase method ///////////////////// -->
    <title>
      the login form
    </title>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.1/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyBgFUWzUrmLXVuKtGtChe2I2zvf5sYga54",
        authDomain: "skool-1083c.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://skool-1083c.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "skool-1083c",
        storageBucket: "skool-1083c.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "911580445409"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Admin Login</h1>
    <form class="form" action="new_blank">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" id="email"autofocus><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="pasword" id="password" ><br></br>
    <input type="submit" value="login" id="sign-in"> 
    <br>



    </form>
    <!-- ///////////////stylesheet///////////// -->


     <script>    
        document.querySelector('#sign-in').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          var email = document.querySelector('#email').value;
          var password = document.querySelector('#password').value
          var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);

          window.alert(credential);
            var auth = firebase.auth();
          var currentUser = auth.currentUser;

          // Step 2
          //  Get a credential with firebase.auth.emailAuthProvider.credential(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value)
          //  If there is no current user, log in with auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
          //  If there is a current user an it's anonymous, atttempt to link the new user with firebase.auth().currentUser.link(credential) 
          //  The user link will fail if the user has already been created, so catch the error and sign in.
        });
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: @PeterHaddad i have made firebase database and that i want to use in this wepage first i want to authenticate using email and password.

Comment: what are the rules you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign in user with email+password on Firebase Authentication, follow the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth). From there, the example to sign in is:

> ```
> firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
>   // Handle Errors here.
>   var errorCode = error.code;
>   var errorMessage = error.message;
>   // ...
> });
> ```

To detect when a user signs in, follow the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user). From there:

> ```
> firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
>   if (user) {
>     // User is signed in.
>   } else {
>     // No user is signed in.
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: Actually i added the project in the android first...therefore the android logo is shoiwing on the project but when add another app i.e. Web app in the project overview of the firebase dashboard it just shows me to add project and the website logo i.e </> is not shown......i think this is the problem i can't access the firebase databse

Comment: The code you shared is about authentication, but will not log the user in. My answer shows how to do this correctly. None of the code you shared accesses the database, so it's hard to help with that. Check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to improve the chances that we can actually help you.

Comment: I just want to know how the authentication with same user id and password will be access to my web code.......i am done with android authentication code....Thanks for replying

Answer (score 0):

> implement firebase auth in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
```

> use enterd user id and password with this function

```
private void login() {
            FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(usrId, usrPass).addOnCompleteListener(loginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(loginActivity.this, "Not sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        startActivity(new Intent(loginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                }
            });
```